# get facebook user first ever made status in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have tried to get a facebook user First ever status in my rails app.

I tried this

```
SELECT status_id,time,message FROM status WHERE uid=me() AND source = 0 ORDER BY status_id ASC LIMIT 1
```

but it is not getting the first ever made status

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT status_id,time,message FROM status WHERE uid=me() AND source = 0 ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1
```

The above query works good. I just replaced status_id with time to sort the result by time (Unix Timestamp where the least is earliest)

Comment: It returns first of latest 100 statuses not first of all user statuses made from the begining